# UIWebView warning in Xamarin Forms iOS

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, telerik

Sending my .ipa to Apple, I received this warning:

```
Apple will no longer accept submissions of new apps that use UIWebView as of April 30, 2020 and app updates that use UIWebView as of December 2020. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview).
```

I followed carefully [this solution](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/uiwebview-deprecation-xamarin-forms/)

- Forms 4.5 or newer.
- Xamarin.iOS 13.10.0.17
- Visual Studio 16.4.3
- This flag in the additional mtouch arguments field: *--optimize=experimental-xforms-product-type*

Still getting the warning.

I think it is because I references Telerik controls in my project, but I also followed this [solution](https://www.telerik.com/forums/uiwebview-deprecation)

No luck yet

[image]

Comment: If you have followed all the steps in the [document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=macos#uiwebview-deprecation-and-app-store-rejection-itms-90809) and make sure you don't have any references to `UIWebView` or `WebViewRenderer` in your own code, the warning should disappear. Have a look at these threads for more help: [UIWebView Apple Deprecation April 2020](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/9823#issuecomment-616538863) and [UIWebview issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/xamarin-docs/issues/2726#issuecomment-613375830).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This post](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/xamarin-docs/issues/2726) has the answer

In my project I have as a nuget a reference to

> Xamarin.Forms.Visual.Material

and this internally references to

> Xamarin.iOS.MaterialComponents

The version of the components was old (72) so I added as a new nuget the latest version Xamarin.iOS.MaterialComponents, (nowadays it is 92), uploaded a new .IPA and the error dissapeared.

Comment: Can you please mark this answer later which will help more people with same problem:).